# Installed Delock PCI Express Card now nusb3mon.exe block 1 cpu core

Tags: windows-7, usb, usb-3, delock

I installed a PCI USB 3.0 card and now one out of four cpu's keeps up running nusb3mon.exe. 
Meaning that I have a CPU load of 25% all the time. Did anyone have the same problem before?

http://www.delock.de/produkte/F_319_USB-3-0_89315/treiber.html?setLanguage=en

[image]

Had no problems with the onboard USB 3.0 ports of my Asus M4A89GDT.
Operating system Window7 64bit

Comment: what happens when you kill the process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Driver update seem to solve the problem. Should have tried that first :-(
Therefore, if anyone has the same problem the drivers from the CD, which came along with the card, are not working correctly.
I will update if problem occurs again.

http://www.via-labs.com/en/products/vl800/index.jsp